# How do I add a line break in my Twilio SMS message?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, newline, twilio

Using Java/Scala.  I am sending this string (an sms message) to a user mobile number by a Twilio Account.

```
var body = "Hello from Govind Singh Nagarkoti! Your verification code is " + code
```

This goes out to the user mobile, in 1 line.

I want a newline after the first sentence.  I want the user to receive:

```
"Hello from Govind Singh Nagarkoti!
 Your verification code is 240190"
```

How can I enter a line break?

Comment: Try %0D%0A as line break

Comment: @Jens  user getting as it is message with %0D%0A

Comment: Hey! Twilio employee here. Have you tried writing a multiline string with a return carriage in it? That works for me (in Python).

Comment: @phalt \n works for me

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you are using an [official Twilio library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries), the proper syntax is `\n`.

In your case, this should work:

```
var body = "Hello from Govind Singh Nagarkoti! \n Your verification code is " + code
```

Answer (score 12):

Just a tip to anyone else who tries to use `\n` to take the content to a new line: the "`\n`" has to be within double quotes; if it's contained within single quotes it will print out as '`\n`'.

Answer (score 9):

Use %0a , it might be helpful.

Reference :http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-in-my-sms-message

Comment: user getting as it is message with %0a

Comment: As far I understood  curl -X is a command line client tool for URL manipulations,it meant making a call to the REST API given with the sets of data.U might try with \n once

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `\n` with single quotes

```scala
val body = s"Hello from Govind Singh Nagarkoti!\nYour verification code is $code"
```

or a new line with triple quotes:

```scala
var body = s"""Hello from Govind Singh Nagarkoti! 
Your verification code is $code"""
```

Note that I also used string interpolation here by prefixing the variable with `$` and prefixing the string with `s`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your IDE doesn't automatcally add another \ if you copy pasted "\n".
This is what tripped me. I pasted "\n" and it got inserted as "\\n" so naturaly the first "\" made the second "\" the special character and resulted in the "n" being treated as a simple "n" character. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` works , and i was trying for, `%0a`

```
var body = "Hello from Govind Singh Nagarkoti!\n Your verification code is " + code
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is struggling with this in Node.js specifically maybe this will help.

I tried all of the above and nothing worked.  In my case the notification.msgText was coming from a database and the \n were in the string returned from the db.  Nothing I tried worked, until I did the following.  I used the | as a placeholder in the database, and then replaced it on the call to twillio.  Hopefully this might save you from pulling out a hair or two.

```
const rsp = await twilioClient.messages
    .create({
        body: notification.msgText.replace(/\|/g, "\n"),
        from: twilioFromNum,
        to: `+1${notification.cellPhone}`
});
```